# Unityの3Dで長さの単位をcmにする方法を教えてください

Tags: unity3d

## デフォルトの単位

Unityのデフォルトはメートルのようです。これでは、今の私のプロジェクトではでかすぎるので、cmにする方法はありますでしょうか？（重さについては[別途質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73919/unity%E3%81%AE3d%E3%81%A7%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D%E3%82%92%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)しています）

下記参考資料の[ひとつ](http://patio.work/archives/1075)は

> ゲーム全体の重力を変更するには、
> Edit→Project Settings→Physicsで出てくる、InspectorにあるPhysicsManagerのGravityのY値を-9.81から変更すればOKです。
>
> やや動きに違和感もありますが、とりあえずこれで様子を見てみます！

というように、重力をいじってなんとかしようとしている例がありますが、純粋に単位を制作しているものに適したもので作成したいです。

私のデフォルトの単位についての感想としては次に引用する記事と同じ気持ちです。

[【開発日記】Unity上のオブジェクトサイズがとても大きいことに気付いたお話 | ゴマちゃんフロンティア](https://gomafrontier.com/unity/1727)

> Unity上での1m (メートル) は「デフォルトのCubeの1辺」に相応するそうです。Cubeの大きさはXYZ全て1で生成されるので、0.5にすれば50cm、10にすれば10mになります。
> それをベースに現在使用しているマイキャラクターの現実的な大きさを考えてみると、モチーフが「ウサギ」とか「リス」とかの動物系なので、2足歩行とはいえ30cm前後が妥当なラインでしょう。

> うーん…やっぱり既存の寸法がぶっ飛んだ大きさです。
> 確かにUnity標準のオブジェクト (特にTerrain) を扱っているときに自前のオブジェクトが大きいと感じたことはありましたが、実際の尺で考えると思った以上に大きくなっている印象です。ざっくり現実世界で例えると「2階建て一軒家」くらいの高さになります。そりゃ物理演算ももっさりするわけで…。

（ここでの「もっさり」とはおそらく大きな物体を遠くから見ているのでもっさりしているように見えるということだと思いますが）

### 長さの単位についての参考資料

[Unityのスプライトの単位についてまとめておく - 渋谷ほととぎす通信](https://www.shibuya24.info/entry/sprite_unit)

> Unityの単位はメートル

[Unityの単位系を理解してなかったせいでオブジェクトの動作がおかしかった件 | パティオ](http://patio.work/archives/1075)

> どうやら0.7ｍで2キログラムのコインを使ったコイン落としゲームを作っていたようです。

Answer (score 1):

9.81という地表近くの重力の定数にも単位があって、9.81 m/s^2 です。見ての通り、メートルが単位の一部にあるので、計算するときには長さはすべてメートルにしなければなりません。センチメートルで計算したいのなら、重力の定数の単位の方を変換しなければなりません。

```
9.81 m/s^2 == 981 cm/s^2
```

なので、長さをすべてメートルに変換するか、参考資料のように重力の定数を変更するかの二択です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。なるほど、たしかに重力加速度にmが含まれているので、すべてmで考えたほうが、わかりやすそうな気がしますね。とはいえ、質問に書かずに申し訳ないですが、いろいろな設定に1を記載すると1mでは小さなものを作るのに毎回小数点を入力しないといけませんが、こういうものなのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問に "私のデフォルトの単位についての感想としては次に引用する記事と同じ気持ちです。"  を追記しました。